# How to write String with slashes to JSON

Tags: json, date, arduino, format

I am trying to send formatted date with slashes to firebase in JSON, via ESP32 http, but output says:

> Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.

How i can send formatted data example xx/xx/xxxx?

formatting date:

```
    gpsdate += gps.date.day();    <- Ok
    gpsdate += "\/";              <- Not Ok
    gpsdate += gps.date.month();  <- Ok
    gpsdate += "\/"               <- Not Ok
    gpsdate += gps.date.year();   <- Ok
```

data sending:

```
String gpsData = "{";
  gpsData += "\"lat\":" + latitude + ",";  <- Ok
  gpsData += "\"lng\":" + longitude + ","; <- Ok
  gpsData += "\"date\":" + gpsdate + "";   <- Not Ok
  gpsData += "}";                          <- Ok
```

output:

```
Data:{"lat":0.717468,"lng":0.798077,"date":8/5/2022}
Status code: 400
Response: {
  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."
}
```

I mean i can do

```
    gpsdate += gps.date.day();
    gpsdate += gps.date.month();
    gpsdate += gps.date.year();
```

but the error occurs with if's... :

```
    if (gps.date.day() < 10) gpsdate += "0";
    gpsdate += gps.date.day();
    if (gps.date.month() < 10) gpsdate += "0";
    gpsdate += gps.date.month();
    gpsdate += gps.date.year();
```

That's how i am sending the data:

```
  PostToFirebase("PATCH", FIREBASE_PATH, gpsData, &http_client);


void PostToFirebase(const char* method, const String & path , const String & data, HttpClient* http) {
...
  http->put(url, contentType, data);
...
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with "\/"? / doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: I have the same error with "/", im trying every possible way to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not know anything about dates.
You should decide on the date formatting and just wrap the date as a string then it should be parsable.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {"lat":0.717468,"lng":0.798077,"date":"8/5/2022"}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"lat": 0.717468, "lng": 0.798077, "date": "8/5/2022"}'
```

Comment: i edited the post, i cant "edit string manually"